# 特定のメソッドのエイリアスがあれば表示する方法

Tags: ruby

`Hash#delete`が破壊的メソッドのせいで `String#delete`が非破壊だと忘れてしまうことが良くあるので、`String#remove`のようなエイリアス関数を作ろうかと思ったのですが、既に存在した場合無駄なので特定のメソッドのエイリアスが現在の環境で既に用意されているかどうかを調べる方法が知りたいです。

今はGoogleで検索したりドキュメントでそれらしい関数がないか探しているのですが、もっと明確に特定のメソッドのエイリアス一覧を表示する方法はなにかないでしょうか？

#### 追記

@sakuro さんに教えて頂いた `Object.instance_method` を使って書いてみました。

```
class Object
  def self.method_aliases
    instance_methods.group_by do |i|
      instance_method(i)
    end.select { |k, v| v.size > 1 }.map { |k, v| v }
  end

  def self.aliases_of(method_symbol)
    method_aliases&.find { |i| i.include?(method_symbol) }&.reject { |i| i == method_symbol }
  end
end

Hash.aliases_of(:has_key?)
# => [:include?, :key?, :member? ]
```

ただ、Rails環境で試してみた所 `[:byebug,:debugger]` や `[:awesome_inspect, :ai]`など一部の gemで拡張してるメソッドが拾えないようです。`group_by`の比較演算子の問題でしょうか…？

Comment: `[:byebug,:debugger]` などはgroup_byで同じキーに配置されないようですね。 性質からしてgroup_byの同値判定には `eql?` が使われているのかと思いましたが、 `Array.instance_method(:byebug).eql?(Array.instance_method(:debugger))` の結果はtrueになります。どのように同値判定してグループ分けしているのか不思議です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コードとしてはダサいですが、 @ironsand さんのコードを元に `group_by` の問題を回避したら、それらしき結果が得られました。

```
class Object
  def self.method_aliases
    instance_methods.group_by do |i|
      instance_method(i)
    end.select { |k, v| v.size > 1 }.map { |k, v| v }
  end

  def self.method_aliases
    grp = instance_methods.inject({}) do |h, i|
      k = h.keys.find { |e| e.eql?(instance_method(i)) }
      if k.nil? then h[instance_method(i)] = [i]
      else h[k] << i
      end
      h
    end
    grp.select { |_, v| v.size > 1 }.values
  end

  def self.aliases_of(method_symbol)
    method_aliases&.find { |i| i.include?(method_symbol) }&.reject { |i| i == method_symbol }
  end
end

puts "aliases of Hash#key? => #{Hash.aliases_of(:key?)}"
# => aliases of Hash#key? => [:include?, :has_key?, :member?]
puts "aliases of Array#byebug => #{Array.aliases_of(:byebug)}"
# => aliases of Array#byebug => [:debugger]
```

Comment: `group_by`の実装に`inject`を使ってこのように書けるんですね、ありがとうございます。`group_by`の同値判定について探してみたんですが、わからなかったので別の質問を立てることにします。

Answer (score 3):

```
if String.method_defined?(:delete)
  class String
    alias :remove :delete
  end
end

puts "hello".remove "o" # hell
```

`method_defined?` を使ってメソッドの存在をチェック出来ます。

Comment: 質問は特定の名前のメソッド(例: `delete` ) というメソッドがあるかどうかではなく、そのメソッドのエイリアスの一覧を取る手法ではないでしょうか？イメージとしては、`String.aliases(:delete)` でシンボルの配列を返すようなものかと。

Comment: あー。失礼しました > all

Comment: 「すでに定義済みなら無駄なのでaliasしない」というのが質問の本題であれば、aliasかどうかはあまり重要ではないのでこれで十分なように思います。

Answer (score 3):

```
Array.instance_methods.combination(2).select {|a,b|
  Array.instance_method(a) == Array.instance_method(b)
}
```

あたりの結果を使って判定できそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ2つ以上の`alias`でうまくいかないの書いてみたのです、上手く書けませんでしたので質問に詳細を追記しておきました。